# How do I position my jQuery element relative to another element

Tags: jquery, wrapper, css-position

I want to position my jQuery element relative to my page Wrapper. I have the entire page contained within a div called Wrapper. My current code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('a.poplightOne').hover(function(e) {
        var html =    '<div id="infoOne">'
        html +=     '</div>';               
        $('body').append(html).children('#infoOne').hide().fadeIn(400);
        $('#infoOne').css({
            position: 'absolute',
        top: '10px',
            left: '10px
    });
}, function() {
    $('#infoOne').remove();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If Wrapper is the id of your container div, can't you just append your html to that instead of body?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('a.poplightOne').hover(function(e) {
        var html =    '<div id="infoOne">'
        html +=     '</div>';               
        $('#Wrapper').append(html).children('#infoOne').hide().fadeIn(400);
        $('#infoOne').css({
            position: 'absolute',
        top: '10px',
            left: '10px
    });
}, function() {
    $('#infoOne').remove();
});
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure if I'm understanding it properly.  If you want your div to come after your Wrapper element then your js looks fine, but you'll have to change your css so body is relative and both your Wrapper and new element need to have relative css with a possible float.

Comment: I have been searching for the answer to this problem for a WEEK! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [`$('#referenceElement').position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) or perhaps [`$('#referenceElement').offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), depending on how you want to locate.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of different methods for DOM manipulation and appending elements to the DOM in various orders.  Here are some:

[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

[after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

[before()](http://api.jquery.com/before)

Just go to api.jquery.com and look through the options.

If you mean to place it near/over/above another element on the page, you can use [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to find out where your existing element is and set up your new one where ever you want, using that as a basis.

Comment: They already have the elements contained in the wrapper, they want to use the wrapper as a reference point to the children's location. (They even use append within their code).

Comment: @Brad, aha, when @Stephanie said 'my jQuery element', I didn't realize she meant the one she was already producing.  'Position' is a somewhat ambiguous term when talking about DOM manipulation, too, so my initial read was DOM positioning rather than pixel positioning.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$(function() {
    $('a.poplightOne').hover(function(e) {
        var leftvar=e.pageX;
        var topvar=e.pageY;
        var html =    '<div id="infoOne">'
        html +=     '</div>';               
        $('body').append(html).children('#infoOne').hide().fadeIn(400);
        $('#infoOne').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: topvar,
            left: leftvar
        });

     });
});
```